# I want to insert the difference(in years) between joining date and current date and add it in a new column for each row

Tags: mysql, database

```
create table emp_details(
empId varchar(10),
empName varchar(20),
designation varchar(30),
band varchar(5),
joiningDate date,
);

insert into salary_struct.emp_details values
('E0001','abc','Trainee software engineer','E','2021-06-01'),
('C2002','xyz','senior business analyst','C2','2017-02-15');
```

How to add a new column called 'experience' in the existing table where I want to add the difference between the joining date and current date in years?

Comment: *add a new column* ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN *add the difference between the joining date and current date in years* UPDATE and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ...)

Comment: Does the new column value must be static (calculated today it stays unchanged tomorrow, even if the difference increases) or dynamic (always equal to actual difference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due the fact the `experience` column is a dynamically calculated  value  instead of store the value in a new db column you could easy obtain the result in a selected column

```
select empId ,
empName ,
designation ,
band ,
joiningDate ,
DATEDIFF(curdate(), joiningDate)
from emp_details experience
```